# Elasticsearch - preIndex

Tags: elasticsearch, listener

I am working on a maintenance task mentioned which will intercepts the ES index operation and - under certain circumstances - changes the field's contents.

My question is: How can I manipulate the documents? There is an index.docs() method. For instance, I fetch the first (and only) document, add a field and then want it to be persisted, but unfortunately, the field won't get set / or removed.

Example:

```
indexingService.addListener(new IndexingOperationListener() {

    @Override
    public Index preIndex(Engine.Index index) {

        List<Document> docs = index.docs();

        List<Document> finalDocs = new ArrayList<Document>();

        for (Document d : docs) {

            d.removeField("field1");

            finalDocs.add(d);
        }

        index.docs().clear();

        index.docs().addAll(finalDocs);

        return index;

    }

});
```

Anything I do wrong? The removed field won't be persisted :(

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Did the answer help? You might want to accept it or upvote if so?

Comment: Hi, yes it did help. Sorry for the delay. Thanks :)

Comment: Cool, thanks for getting back to me ;)

Comment: Hi Jan, Can you please share some sudo code or example regarding implementing IndexingOperationListener through plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the `IndexingOperationListener` wasn't meant to modify documents, the code looks good. The only thing is that you're only modifying the lucene document that gets indexed, which won't contain the field you are removing. If you don't want it in the source either you have to modify the source too. But I think even though you see the field in your docs, you can't actually search on it, since it's not in lucene. If you can search on it and get results, then you need to make sure that your custom code actually runs.

Also, you don't need to clear the list and add all the docs again. You can just modify the documents in your loop, that's it.

Comment: Hi Javanna,
Can you please share some examples with IndexingOperationListener implementations because i am not getting where to hook my plugin/util to add listener.