# Elasticsearch Database Listener using Java High level Rest Client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, java-client

I want to create a ***database listener*** for **Elasticsearch** for all type of operation (insert, delete, update). Where i can get details about document Id, Index name, Operation Type etc.

I have heard of ***IndexingOperationListener*** but not sure how to implement for my case.

Thanks,
Darsan

Comment: Not sure if this is the way to go..IndexingOperationListener seem rather Internal.

Comment: Thanks For the reply, Not sure about that. but here you can check that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18823546/elasticsearch-preindex.
I think they have used for the same.